# 'deviceorientation' in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm working with 'deviceorientation' on my laptop and an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/3x2zZ/) seems to work fine in Chrome but is not responding in Firefox.  I think that line 15 of JS is not working somehow...

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', devOrientHandler, false);
```

The MozOrientation version on line 18 doesn't seem to be picking up the slack

```
window.addEventListener('MozOrientation', mozDevOrientHandler, false);
```

Just updated Firefox. And no change.  I've tried to test on a desktop and (unsurprisingly) the machine doesn't seem to have the necessary accelerometers/sensors so the fiddle doesn't work on any browser on that machine.  I've been scouring questions, reading the w3c specs, the [MDN support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation) and I still can't get it.

Does anybody know if this is a Firefox issue? Did I mess up settings or something? Any help is much appreciated.  Any ideas as to why that example jsfiddle isn't working on Firefox?
note: the example "green ball" in the MDN link above isn't working on FF either.  First time asking a question on SO.

Thanks!

Edit: I should clarify that the jsfiddle is the best example I could find, and is NOT my code. I believe it was from HTML5rocks.com but I can't find that source.

Comment: OT: You should remember to include the non-webkit version of perspective in your CSS also, for other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox does not, at this time of writing, expose `DeviceOrientation` events on any Desktop platform. Your event handler is not triggered in Firefox simply for the reason that the API is not enabled in their Desktop browser builds.

On the other hand, Chromium-based browsers have enabled DeviceOrientation events with some important caveats. Chromium-based browsers generally only return DeviceOrientation events consistently on Mac OS X due to the general availability of gyro + accelerometer hardware sensors that are available in Apple computers. Additionally, Chromium-based browsers report the `event.alpha` value as `undefined` due to no compass or magnetic sensors being available to compute that correctly.

The situation on *mobile* browsers is much better and is arguably the main target for this API. All major mobile browsers (Safari on iOS, Chrome/Opera/Firefox on Android) do support this event in its un-prefixed form i.e. `window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) { /* ... */ }, false)`.